# After updating Anaconda-Navigator environments dont work

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I updated Anaconda-Navigator to 1.9.12 on ubuntu and now my environments dont work. 
I can still start a jupyter notebook from the environment but all my installed packages are not available even though they are displayed in the anaconda-navigator gui under installed packages for this env. 
but when I import a package in a notebook : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ....
The standard packages like numpy are available though...

Please help me... why did I update!!!!????

maybe a path problem? Please help me in simple terms

Thanks

Comment: How did you update Anaconda Navigator? What happens if you run a program from the command line, do you still get the same ModuleNotFoundError?

Comment: Ah interesting from the command line the environment still works, so a jupyter notebook problem? I updated by supididly clicking on an reoccuring update popup in the gui of anaconda navigator

Comment: _so a jupyter notebook problem_ Probably. Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: I have 195 packages installed, everything jupyter notebook related should be: ipykernel                 5.1.3  
jupyter                   1.0.0  
jupyter_client            5.3.4  
jupyter_console           6.0.0 
jupyter_core              4.6.1  
jupyterlab                1.2.6 
jupyterlab_server         1.0.7  
notebook                  6.0.3    
nbconvert                 5.6.1
nbformat                  4.4.0

Comment: have tried updating numpy?

Comment: numpy is on the current version

Comment: 195! How many of those are top-level dependencies, though (packages that you've explicitly installed) ? Can you try creating a new environment?

Comment: I just now created a new env with "conda create -n keras_env keras python=3.6"
so the deepLearning package keras+ dependencies is installed, then I installed Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3 via the gui and now I can not access keras in a notebook from this env
so new env same problem???

Comment: In the environment you just created, can you share the versions of the jupyter-related packages (you can get that information using `conda list`) ? What happens if you install all the packages at once, using something like `conda create -n keras_env python=3.6 keras jupyterlab` ?

Comment: ok I found a solution. Normally lazy me starts my env (and then notebook) from the gui and it seems this is now broken. but when doing 'conda activate env' and then 'jupyter notebook' it works... I will never update anything again!!!! btw I did your command still gui broken...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help and time, you brought me on the track to find some way to enter my envs. broken gui -not desirable. but still... I can work again.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. My experiance is that when you upgrade to Navigator to 1.9.12.
the enviroment variables in GUI(Navigator UI), are taken from base enviroment not from second enviroment and if you work from console it work, so it looks like it not executes conda activate new_environment in gui. When you work from terminal everythings works fine.
To be honest it has the same behaviour if fresh install last anaconda too. This was the reason i have downgraded conda isntallation, and than i found out that last version of navigator was making the issues . Or you can downgrade:
conda install anaconda-navigator=1.9.7.